# Enable backcolor (background color) button for Fishpig Wordpress Magento 2

Tags: magento2, wordpress

I would like to enable the background color button for Wordpress text editor in Wordpress admin. The button is disabled by default. Is there any way to enable it? I've looked for guides/tutorials online, but there are none for Magento specifically.